# bitwise operation in c about mask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Here is the question, write a produre

```
void compress(char *str, char mask)
```

that compress the string according to the specified 8- bit mask. for example, if str is

```
The quick red fox jumped
```

and the binary representation of mask is

```
10110011
```

the resulting value of str would be

```
Th ickrefoxjued
```

This result is determined by duplicating the mask for every group of eight characters and eliminating characters masked by a 0 bit:

```
The quick red fox jumped
101100111011001110110011
```

Note: the string being compress might bot be a multiple of eight characters in length, as it is in this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void compress(char *, unsigned char);
int main()
{
    unsigned char mask = 179;
    char *str;
    str = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", str);
    compress(str, mask);
    return 0;
}

void compress(char *str, unsigned char mask)
{
    float len = strlen(str);
    int times;

    if (len / 8 > (int)(len / 8))
    {
        times = (int)(len / 8 + 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        mask = mask << 8 | 0263;
    }
    unsigned bit = 1u << (8 * times);
    for (char *p = str; *p; p++)
    {
        for ( ; bit ; bit >>= 1)
        {
            if ((bit & mask) > 0)
            {
                printf("%c", *p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, I the output is not what I want, can someone help thx.

Comment: "the output is not what I want" Please be more specific than that. What is the actual output? And what was the input and expected output? "The quick red fox jumped" and "Th ickredfoxjued" like in the example? As far as I can tell the output for that input and the given mask should actually be "Te ickredfoxjued".

Comment: PS: You take `mask` as a parameter, but then still hardcode the number `0263` in the body, which will cause broken behavior when you call your function with any parameter except `0263` and the fact that you spell it as `0263` in `compress`, but 179 in `main` makes this even more confusing.

Comment: `float len = strlen(str);` doesn't make sense - `strlen` always returns an integral number, a string length cannot be a floating point

Comment: Also `times` is potentially uninitialized since it is only set it the `if` condition is true, so your code invokes *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your issue (change compress function as follow):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

void compress(char *str, unsigned char mask)
{
    // And as others said You can avoid using strlen
    //int len = strlen(str);
    //for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    for(int i=0;str[i];i++)
    {
        if(((mask >> (7 - (i%8))) & 0x01))
            printf("%c", str[i] );
    }
}

int main()
{
   unsigned char mask = 179;
    char *str;
    str = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(str, 100,stdin);
    compress(str, mask);
    return 0;
}
```

I've used fgets instead of scanf because scanf does not read space.

```
The quick red fox jumped
Te ickrefoxjued
```

Comment: Thx man, I forget about scanf cant read space, you right, should use fgets. my old one can only output "T"